# Strange AZ Function logs - Linux different to windows logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I've swapped my AZ Functions to linux (Cheaper), and the logs I'm getting are vastly different from the Windows ones.

How can I get my windows style logs, in linux.

Host.json:

```
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
```

(And is it normally it appears to be constantly restarting? Its running as expected.

EventHub Trigger and writing to a SQL Db fine)

Linux:

```
2022-05-26T12:32:25  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.

Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----

/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/32d570889ada5fffd4821e889d028629adf71f5ff36ea7394911d6816e8e8aff.log 
2022-05-26T12:08:53.855237110Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [SystemAssigned] Added Identity with ClientId: <CLIENT-ID>
2022-05-26T12:08:53.856038609Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Starting TokenService from /app with the following: IsLinuxDedicated: True, IsLinuxConsumption: False, IsWindows: False.
2022-05-26T12:08:53.970340540Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production
2022-05-26T12:08:53.970368740Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /app
2022-05-26T12:08:53.970380340Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
2022-05-26T12:08:53.970385040Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2022-05-26T12:08:54.993790139Z: [INFO]  function-name : [5986fb39-9525-43c0-a14d-06bfdbe0fb9c] Incoming request on /healthcheck?api-version=2021-08-01
2022-05-26T12:08:59.151768328Z: [INFO]  function-name : [bcc7a3ba-02b1-434c-bfd2-32f04990418f] Incoming request on /robots933456.txt
2022-05-26T12:09:25.450404632Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Configuration update started. Site: function-name
2022-05-26T12:09:25.450426232Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [SystemAssigned] Added Identity with ClientId: <CLIENT-ID>


/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/6acd2cf91b88dfaffb90c31b64b88a8ea919b18e2d1c9d75e97e6a27f39fb89f.log 
2022-05-26T11:12:17.982676382Z: [INFO]  Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2022-05-26T11:12:24.343773510Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production
2022-05-26T11:12:24.343798510Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /azure-functions-host
2022-05-26T11:12:24.343812510Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2022-05-26T11:12:24.343816410Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.


/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/321fcf9de2622c3c3dcc032a4cd3545b35e8797501f155b040b2397e2f7d31ea.log 
2022-05-26T12:07:53.867902158Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [SystemAssigned] Added Identity with ClientId: <CLIENT-ID>
2022-05-26T12:07:53.867933758Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Starting TokenService from /app with the following: IsLinuxDedicated: True, IsLinuxConsumption: False, IsWindows: False.
2022-05-26T12:07:54.147981531Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Production
2022-05-26T12:07:54.148010631Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /app
2022-05-26T12:07:54.148262830Z: [INFO]  Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
2022-05-26T12:07:54.148272330Z: [INFO]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2022-05-26T12:07:55.448095518Z: [INFO]  function-name : [bcd344a8-ebd4-4b29-980c-7139da3f211d] Incoming request on /healthcheck?api-version=2021-08-01
2022-05-26T12:07:58.753565940Z: [INFO]  function-name : [328b58ab-cfca-4cf8-876c-ae705493510d] Incoming request on /robots933456.txt
2022-05-26T12:08:50.957872214Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] Configuration update started. Site: function-name
2022-05-26T12:08:50.957900814Z: [INFO]  function-name : [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [SystemAssigned] Added Identity with ClientId: <CLIENT-ID>
```

Where as my windows logs:

```
 Executing 'Functions.SourceReader' (Reason='(null)', Id=0b300c0f-ed5e-446e-a6ac-4ca6e049cdca)
[2022-05-26T12:37:00.624Z]
[2022-05-26T12:37:00.626Z] Trigger Details: PartionId: 4, Offset: 87823505798976-87823505806248, EnqueueTimeUtc: 2022-05-19T12:30:40.8030000+00:00-2022-05-19T12:30:40.8030000+00:00, SequenceNumber: 677125426-677125435, Count: 10
[2022-05-26T12:37:00.624Z] My Console Log
```

Answer (score 0):

- *Azure linux logs gives Detailed Information about each and every detail because of which logs are more, Syslog is a widely used Linux event logging mechanism. Messages are sent by applications and may be saved locally or forwarded to a Syslog collector. The Log Analytics agent for Linux configures the local Syslog daemon to forward messages to the agent when it is installed. After that, the agent delivers the message to Azure Monitor, which creates a record for it because of which logs are more.*

[image]

- *For more information you can go through the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs%29.).*